# How to define generic function with one concrete type and one inferred type

Tags: typescript, types, typescript-generics

I have a generic function `transform()`, with two type parameters, that transforms an argument of type `A` into type `B`.

```ts
declare const transform: <A, B>(x: A) => A | B

const a = 123 //: number
const b = transform<number, string>(a) //: string
```

Right now, I have to pass in both types but the first type can be inferred from the argument. I want a function that only needs the new type as a concrete input.

**How can I write a generic function that accepts one concrete type and infers the other?**

---

### Edit 1

The implementation behind `transform()` function is not important. Instead, what I need is a way of writing a generic function that infers one type (in this case, the argument) and accepts another type (the return type).

---

### Edit 2

My current alternative is to use a higher-order function (to capture the return type) that returns another function that does the transformation.

```ts
declare const transform: <B>() => <A>(x: A) => A | B

const a = 123 //: number
const b = transform<string>()(a) //: string
```

---

### Edit 3

Add sample implementation for `transform()`

```
const transform: <A, B>(x: A) => A | B = (x) => {
  if (x === null) {
    return null
  }

  if (typeof x === 'number') {
    return x.toString() as any
  }

  return x
}

const a = transform<number, string>(123)
const b = transform<null, boolean>(null)
```

Comment: *"The implementation behind `transform()` function is not important"* I think it is (or rather, some [MCVE](/help/mcve) of it), not least because I can't see how you can correctly achieve the transform when you don't know the type you're transforming to at runtime.

Comment: The sample implementation assumes an input type of `number` and an output type of `String`. But while you can know the former at runtime, you can't know the latter, so...? What problem is this function solving?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder This is why I avoided providing a concrete implementation. My main goal was to achieve something similar to [TypeScript#26349](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/26349) but without the added syntax. But once a function definition is in sight, it overpowers the underlying problem. Perhaps a `transform()` function was simply the wrong choice here.

Answer (score 1):

Accept it as `any` (or a union of types you want it to accept):

```
function transform<T>(x: any): T {
  return x
}

const a = 123 //: number
const b = transform<string>(a) //: string
```

<s>**But**, it's worth noting that the function doesn't actually transform anything. In your example, although TypeScript thinks `b` is a string, **it isn't**. It's still a number. Your function doesn't do anything at runtime at all. If you want to actually transform, you need to do somehing at runtime to make it happen.</s> Your edit suggests you know that. :-)

Comment: Even though the `transform()` function is a simple type-cast, I am using it as a simple example. What the function does is not the main point but rather writing a generic function that infers the argument and accepts the return type.

Comment: @zhirzh - Cool. :-) The above does that.

Comment: @t-j-crowder I have updated the question to clarify what I want to do.

Comment: @zhirzh - I don't see what the higher-order function does for you vs. `any`. You still can't write code relying on the type of the argument (without runtime checks, which will automatically narrow `any` for you).

Comment: @t-j-crowder updated the code snippets and modified the return types. Now, for the sake of example, bothe `type A` & `type B` are necessary.

Comment: @zhirzh - I don't think there's any reasonable other way to answer the question as it stands now than to use `any`. We need to understand more about the internals of `transform`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197122/discussion-between-zhirzh-and-t-j-crowder).